# Changing unboxed of primitive typed (e.g. long, not Long) by reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to change a value of following variable by java reflection:
public final static Long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 100000L;

There is no exception or errors but value remains.

JDK: Oracle 8 JDK.

There is simple class to reproduce the problem.

```
package testpackage;

public class LibraryClass {
  // Changing long to Long fixes the issue
  public final static long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 100000L; 
}
```

Simple test-case. I'm using org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils to remove finale/making the field accessible. I also tried to work with FieldUtils/and class object (because of staticness of the filed= to change value. But every approach failed.

```
public class FinalStaticVariableChangeCheck {

  private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FinalStaticVariableChangeCheck.class);

  @Test
  public void testLChangingLibraryClass()
      throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InterruptedException, InstantiationException {
    LibraryClass sampleClass = new LibraryClass();
    final Class<?> clazz;
    final Field    field;

    clazz = sampleClass.getClass();
    field = clazz.getDeclaredField("DEFAULT_TIMEOUT");

    FieldUtils.removeFinalModifier(field, true);
    field.set(sampleClass, 1234L);

    LOG.info("Output: " + sampleClass.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    Assert.assertEquals(1234L, sampleClass.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);


  }

}
```

The output is 100000.

However, by changing `public final static long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 100000L;` to `public final static Long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 100000L;` solves the problem

Expected: output 1234 and the test-case is not failing.

The issue seems to be related to the unboxed type. Any Ideas how to workaround the problem? Unfortunately the code resides in an external library and my PRs to solve the problem in more elegant way are currently "ignored".

Comment: You may want to consider why you are trying to modify a final variable. The JVM/javac assumes that final variables will not change. Why not just make it not final?

Comment: It is a “bug” in an external library i am trying to fix. Thus, I cannot change it by myself.

Comment: I see. You may find it easier to 1) modify the sources (if possible), 2) decompile, edit, and recompile, or 3) notify the publisher of the library and hope they fix it

Comment: 1) done and issued a PR 2) not really necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
LOG.info("Output: " + sampleClass.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
```

Prints a *constant expression*. That is, given that the variable `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` is final and static, it is considered a constant, so its value is evaluated during compile time, concatenated to `Output`, so effectively, your Java program actually contains the line

```
LOG.info("Output: 100000");
```

Once you run it, it doesn't matter that you have changed the value of the field. It is no longer looked up. It just prints the above string.

Sometimes involving a variable that is not constant in the print expression may work - but it's not guaranteed. The compiler can inline the value of the constant anyway, as it is, itself, a constant expression - which is why the assert statement fails.

Comment: Indeed. I looked into the decompiled code and the variable is replaced everywhere through the the corresponding constant.